# how to autohide commands in LWUIT Form

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-form

I have a LWUIT Form which has 3 containers, each with its own content. Two commands('BackCommand' & 'ExitCommand') have been added to the form.

These commands are shown at the bottom of the screen. The commands hog up quite a lot of space on the screen. Can I auto hide these commands the way we can autohide a taskbar in windows?

Whenever the user pressed the left/right soft button, I want the two commands to pop-up and then become active for receiving events generated by the form.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to derive the `MenuBar` class introduced in LWUIT 1.5 and override the functionality of the menu bar any way you like e.g. setting the MenuBar to visible "false" within the form.

Answer (score 1):

To hide the command's bar write in the `class` of your `Form` :

```
removeCommand(BackCommand);
removeCommand(ExitCommand);
```

To reshow the `command`s you must overide the `keyReleased(int keycode)` method and get the `gameAction` of the key pressed by using `Display.getInstance().getGameAction(keycode)`. To do this : first show the value of the gameAction of the two softbuttons in a Dialog, then in your `if` test `compare` the `getGameAction` to these numbers.

Comment: ah..not this way man...thats a lot of code...looking for something better. but hey thanks!

Comment: you see... i'll have to add the commands again after the user does not need them to be in focus; that means more code and well that is not so elegant a way... :)